# How to bulk remove items from Bluetooth devices list of windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-11, bluetooth, device-manager

This is how my Bluetooth list looks on windows 11
[image: Bluetooth devices list]

This is polluting my quick connect window. Making it harder to find the device I want to connect to.
[image]

I am looking for a script or even a tool that can quickly clean up this list. I cannot click on remove device for each item because in a week it will be back to this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of Bluetooth device is [stored in the Windows Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bluetooth/bluetooth-registry-entries) at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Devices`.

[image: Bluetooth Devices]

It would be easy to make a script to remove **all** Blutooth devices, with possibly *bad* side effects. Instead, I suggest you **export** [*File -> Export*] the whole BTHPORT key in the state you you prefer, and then **import** it to return to that state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply this was helpful. I will develop a quick script to do this then.